# Buttons won't align properly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, datatables

Rails 4, Ruby 2, Bootstrap 3, DataTables 1.10

Buttons for pagination align properly in IE and Chrome.  They won't align in Firefox.  I tried using this patch [for Firefox](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/button-padding-issue/).  I tried using input-group/input-group-btn.  This code is generated by DataTables.

In Firebug, the funky block in the upper right corner of First refers to ALL the li elements in the HTML in reverse order.  Leftmost is "last", then "next", then "previous, then "first".

Firefox:

[image: Firefox buttons]

Chrome and IE:

[image: Chrome and IE buttons]

HTML generated by DataTables for Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-xs-6" style="outline: medium none;">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate fg-buttonset ui-buttonset fg-buttonset-multi ui-buttonset-multi paging_full" id="adminitemstable_paginate" style="outline: medium none;">
        <ul class="pagination" style="outline: medium none;">
            <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default first disabled" aria-controls="adminitemstable" tabindex="0" id="adminitemstable_first" style="outline: medium none;">
                <a href="#" style="outline: medium none;">
                    First
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default previous disabled" aria-controls="adminitemstable" tabindex="0" id="adminitemstable_previous" style="outline: medium none;">
                <a href="#" style="outline: medium none;">
                    Previous
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default next" aria-controls="adminitemstable" tabindex="0" id="adminitemstable_next" style="outline: medium none;">
                <a href="#" style="outline: medium none;">
                    Next
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="fg-button ui-button ui-state-default last" aria-controls="adminitemstable" tabindex="0" id="adminitemstable_last" style="outline: medium none;">
                <a href="#" style="outline: medium none;">
                    Last
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Vucko The fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/wszd0bt7/7/.  However, IE and Chrome both drop the Last button in it.  The Firefox display is similar to that shown here except it doesn't show the funky box in the upper right corner of First, at least that I can see...

Comment: @R_G you are mixing Jquery UI(using fg-button, ui-state-default classes) with Bootstrap and hence the styling issues. They do have [example for bootstrap](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) on their site. [Fiddle using datatable's bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/wszd0bt7/22/)

Comment: @anpsmn This entire table is built using DataTables with the jquery-datatables-rails gem, so that is where that mixed styling originates.

Comment: OBTW, where did all our comments from the last couple of days go???

Comment: @R_G Though you got the issue solved, you can post this query as an issue there on the plugin page as this is strange that they are mixing classes. Could be some mismatch of versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set as like this to set

```css
.fg-button {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Live **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/qo24bzs9/)**

Comment: Where is the class "fg-button" stored?

Comment: @ i am not... in over extra style sheet.